# Counting "double bonds" in graphs

Tags: graph-theory, chemistry

Here's an interesting puzzle I've set myself. Consider the set of [multigraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph) (or, if you prefer, graphs with edges weighted by positive integers), excluding graphs with cycles of length 1. Let the degree of a vertex be the number of edges connected to it. (Or if you prefer weighted graphs, the sum of the weights on the edges connected to it.) Let the *signature* of a graph be the [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) containing the number of degrees of each of its vertices. For example, consider the following multigraph:

[image]

It has signature $\{4, 4, 1, 1\}$, since two of its nodes are connected to four edges and two to one edge. (Note that this graph is reminiscent of an [acetylene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetylene) molecule, with its signature corresponding to its chemical formula, $\mathrm{H_2C_2}$. This chemical analogy is the motivation for the question.) Note that the total number of edges in a multigraph is equal to half the sum of the elements of its signature.

I'm interested in the number of *multiple edges* (double bonds, triple bonds etc.) in a given graph. That is, the number of pairs of vertices that are connected by more than one edge. For the signature $\{4, 4, 1, 1\}$ there is always a multiple edge, because the only graph with that signature is the one above. On the other hand, $\{3,1,1,1\}$ (an ammonia-like graph) only has single bonds.

Some signatures correspond to more than one graph ("isomers" in chemistry terminology) - for example, $\{4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1\}$ may have either two double edges or one triple one. Some, such as $\{2, 1\}$ do not correspond to any graph.

My questions are as follows:

- given a multiset of integers, what are the necessary and sufficient conditions for it to be the signature of a multigraph?
- given a signature, is there a way to tell whether its corresponding graphs have multiple bonds, short of enumerating all graphs with that signature?
- what can be deduced about the number of multiple edges in a graph from its signature alone, short of enumerating all graphs with that signature?
- is there a graph with no multiple edge that shares a signature with a graph with at least one multiple edge?

Comment: For the first, you need the sum of degrees to be both even and at least double the largest degree

Comment: I suspect Henry's condition is morally close to a characterization when applied recursively (take the largest pair of degrees and subtract 1 from each degree to represent an edge, then re-sort and repeat).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your 'multiset of integers' or signature is generally called 'degree sequence'.
Your question is about graphs and multigraphs realizing certain degree sequences.
Quite a lot has been researched and written about this.

Ad 1: A necessary and sufficient condition is that the sum of all entries is even (@Henry's comment made me realize that this is only correct when loops are allowed as well, when no loops are allowed his answer is the correct one).

Ad 4: Certainly, lots of them. A very simple one is $(2,2,2,2)$ which is realized
by a 4-cycle, but also by 2 thick edges. Or $(3,3,3,3)$ which is realized by
a complete graph $K_4$, but also by a 4-cycle with 2 thick edges.

For realizing a "simple graph", i.e. one without loops and multi-edges one of
the most famous criteria is the Havel-Hakimi condition (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havel%E2%80%93Hakimi_algorithm).

This brings us to

Ad 2: In view of Ad 4, the signatures that have *only* realizations with
multiple bonds are those that do not satisfy the Havel-Hakimi condition, but that do satisfy the condition Ad 1.
Signatures that satisfy the Havel-Hakimi condition will often
have both simple realizations and multigraph realizations.

Ad 3: Again, in view of Ad 4, you cannot expect to find a well-defined number.
The best you can tell (without imposing any other constraints) is, that when the sum of the degrees exceeds $2\binom n2$,
where $n$ is the number of entries/vertices, the number of multiple edges is
at least half of the excess.